# UnExpected Null Value when I Navigate from Signupscreen To LoginScreen after Clicking the Signup Button

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

Following is the Code of Signup:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

import 'loginscreen.dart';

class SignupScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SignupScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SignupScreenState createState() => _SignupScreenState();
}

class _SignupScreenState extends State<SignupScreen> {
  TextEditingController idController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController passController = TextEditingController();

  double screenHeight = 0;
  double screenWidth = 0;

  Color primary = const Color(0xffeef444c);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              height: screenHeight / 2.5,
              width: screenWidth,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: primary,
                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(70),
                ),
              ),
              child: Center(
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.person_add,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  size: screenWidth / 5,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                top: screenHeight / 15,
                bottom: screenHeight / 20,
              ),
              child: Text(
                "Sign Up",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: screenWidth / 20,
                  fontFamily: "NexaBold",
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: screenWidth / 12),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  customTitle("Personal ID"),
                  customInputField(
                    "Enter your Personal ID",
                    idController,
                    false,
                  ),
                  customTitle("Password"),
                  customInputField(
                    "Enter your Password",
                    passController,
                    true,
                  ),
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () async {
                      String id = idController.text.trim();
                      String password = passController.text.trim();

                      if (id.isEmpty) {
                        _showSnackbar("ID is empty");
                      } else if (password.isEmpty) {
                        _showSnackbar("Password is empty");
                      } else {
                        try {
                          await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                              .collection("person")
                              .doc(id)
                              .set({
                            'id': id,
                            'password': password,
                          });

                          _showSnackbar("Signup Successful");
                          // Navigate to Login page after signup
                          Navigator.pushReplacement(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => LoginScreen(),
                            ),
                          );
                        } catch (e) {
                          _showSnackbar("Error: $e");
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      height: 60,
                      width: screenWidth,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: screenHeight / 40),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: primary,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30)),
                      ),
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                          "SIGN UP",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: "NexaBold",
                            fontSize: 17,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            letterSpacing: 2,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _showSnackbar(String message) {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
      content: Text(message),
    ));
  }

  Widget customTitle(String title) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 12),
      child: Text(
        title,
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: screenWidth / 26,
          fontFamily: "NexaBold",
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget customInputField(
      String hint, TextEditingController controller, bool obscure) {
    return Container(
      width: screenWidth,
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 12),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12)),
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.black26,
            blurRadius: 10,
            offset: Offset(2, 2),
          )
        ],
      ),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            width: screenWidth / 8,
            child: Icon(
              Icons.person,
              color: primary,
              size: screenWidth / 15,
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: screenWidth / 12),
              child: TextFormField(
                controller: controller,
                enableSuggestions: false,
                autocorrect: false,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    vertical: screenHeight / 35,
                  ),
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  hintText: hint,
                ),
                maxLines: 1,
                obscureText: obscure,
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Following is The Code for loginScreen:

```
import 'package:app/homescreen.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_keyboard_visibility/flutter_keyboard_visibility.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<LoginScreen> createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  TextEditingController idController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController passController = TextEditingController();

  double screenHeight = 0;
  double screenWidth = 0;

  Color primary = const Color(0xffeef444c);
  late SharedPreferences sharedpref;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final bool isKeyboardVisible =
        KeyboardVisibilityProvider.isKeyboardVisible(context);
    screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: Column(
        children: [
          isKeyboardVisible
              ? SizedBox(
                  height: screenHeight / 16,
                )
              : Container(
                  height: screenHeight / 2.5,
                  width: screenWidth,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: primary,
                    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                      bottomRight: Radius.circular(70),
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.person,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      size: screenWidth / 5,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(
              top: screenHeight / 15,
              bottom: screenHeight / 20,
            ),
            child: Text(
              "Login",
              style:
                  TextStyle(fontSize: screenWidth / 20, fontFamily: "NexaBold"),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: screenWidth / 12),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                custom_Title("Personal ID"),
                custom_input_field(
                    "Enter your Personal ID", idController, false),
                custom_Title("Password"),
                custom_input_field("Enter your Password", passController, true),
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () async {
                    FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
                    String id = idController.text.trim();
                    String password = passController.text.trim();

                    if (id.isEmpty) {
                      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
                        content: Text("Id is Still Empty"),
                      ));
                    } else if (password.isEmpty) {
                      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
                        content: Text("Password is Still Empty"),
                      ));
                    } else {
                      QuerySnapshot snap = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                          .collection("person")
                          .where('id', isEqualTo: id)
                          .get();
                      try {
                        if (password == snap.docs[0]['password']) {
                          sharedpref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

                          sharedpref.setString("personID", id).then((_) {
                            Navigator.pushReplacement(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => HomeScreen()));
                          });
                          sharedpref.setString("personPass", password);
                        } else {
                          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                            content: Text("password incorrect"),
                          ));
                        }
                      } catch (e) {
                        String error = " ";
                        if (e.toString() ==
                            "RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0") {
                          setState(() {
                            error = "Person id does not exist";
                          });
                        } else {
                          setState(() {
                            error = "Error Occured!";
                          });
                        }
                        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                          content: Text(error),
                        ));
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    height: 60,
                    width: screenWidth,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: screenHeight / 40),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: primary,
                      borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30)),
                    ),
                    child: const Center(
                      child: Text(
                        "LOGIN",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: "NexaBold",
                          fontSize: 17,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          letterSpacing: 2,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget custom_Title(String title) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 12),
      child: Text(
        title,
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: screenWidth / 26, fontFamily: "NexaBold"),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget custom_input_field(
      String hint, TextEditingController controller, bool obscure) {
    return Container(
      width: screenWidth,
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 12),
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12)),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.black26, blurRadius: 10, offset: Offset(2, 2))
          ]),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            width: screenWidth / 8,
            child: Icon(
              Icons.person,
              color: primary,
              size: screenWidth / 15,
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: screenWidth / 12),
              child: TextFormField(
                controller: controller,
                enableSuggestions: false,
                autocorrect: false,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    vertical: screenHeight / 35,
                  ),
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  hintText: hint,
                ),
                maxLines: 1,
                obscureText: obscure,
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Now In The SignupScreen, In the following lines :

```
 Navigator.pushReplacement(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => LoginScreen(),
                            ),
                          );
```

I'm getting error of:

> ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY
> ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
> The following TypeErrorImpl was thrown building LoginScreen(dirty, state:
> _LoginScreenState#26f54): Unexpected null value.\
>
> The relevant error-causing widget was:
> LoginScreen
> LoginScreen:file:///D:/attendance%20system/app/lib/signupscreen.dart:104:53
>
> When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
> dart-sdk/lib/*internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 294:3
>
> throw*
> dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 943:18
> nullCheck
> packages/flutter_keyboard_visibility/src/ui/keyboard_visibility_provider.dart 55:10 
> isKeyboardVisible
> packages/app/loginscreen.dart 27:36
> build
> packages/flutter/src/widgets/f

Comment: provide code for KeyboardVisibilityProvider

Comment: either the `KeyboardVisibilityProvider` is null or `KeyboardVisibilityProvider.isKeyboardVisible(context);`  returns null.

Comment: @Anas Nadeem Which code?

Comment: Is it possible the error lies in the context in the Navigator because when I try to move From Login to HomeScreen, it redirects me there ( Duumy Data i already store there for Login ) but when I Navigate from Signup to Login it gives me Null error however the user id, password still stored in the Firebase.